# Website only changes after reload - react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I would like to make a navbar with different Links to different routes. In another file, I have the react-router stuff in order to change the website. But when I press on the links it works but only if I reload afterward.

The head file:

```
export default function Head(props){
    return(
        <Router>            
            <div className="Head">                      
                <div className="HeadItemFirst">bwftp</div>         
                <div className="HeadPaths">                    
                    <Link className="HeadItem" to="/"><div>Start</div></Link>
                    <Link className="HeadItem" to="/about"><div>about</div></Link>
                    <Link className="HeadItem" to="/settings"><div>Settings</div></Link>                        
                </div>                                 
            </div>             
        </Router> 
    )
}
```

And the App file:

```
export default function App(){
   return(
  <div className="App">
  <Head />{/* Here are all the links in a navbar stored */}      
  <Body /> 
  <Foot />

  <Router>         
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" exact component={About}/>
      <Route path="/settings" exact component={Settings}/>
      <Route render={()=>(<h1>404</h1>)}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: wrap your <Head/> inside the bottom router..dont use two router.

Comment: You need only one ```<Router>``` component, remove it from your Head

Answer (score 0):

You need not use multiple router instances in your Application. Instead have one at the topmost parent level. If you use multiple Routes, the Link components inside Head will communicate with the `Router` component inside `Head` only and will not relay the information of `route change to Router in App`

Also if you render Head as a default Route it will receive all props from Route and will ensure smooth functioning of the Routes

```js
export default function Head(props){
    return(
        <div className="Head">                      
            <div className="HeadItemFirst">bwftp</div>         
            <div className="HeadPaths">                    
                <Link className="HeadItem" to="/"><div>Start</div></Link>
                <Link className="HeadItem" to="/about"><div>about</div></Link>
                <Link className="HeadItem" to="/settings"><div>Settings</div></Link>                        
            </div>                                 
        </div>             
    )
}


export default function App(){
   return(
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route component={Head} />    //Render as a default route so that it gets route params
          <Body /> 
          <Foot />         
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" exact component={About}/>
            <Route path="/settings" exact component={Settings}/>
            <Route render={()=>(<h1>404</h1>)}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
  )
}
```